# Defining a destructor prevents member functions being inlined

Tags: c++, inline

I am seeing a strange issue where by member methods aren't getting inlined if I define a destructor.

Example code:

```
#include <cstdio>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int arg) : data(arg) {}
    ~Foo(void) {}

    Foo bar(void) const { return Foo(7); }

    int data;
};

int main(void)
{
        Foo a(3);
        Foo b = a.bar();

        printf ("%i", b.data);
}
```

If using the default destructor, I get something like this:

```
main:
 sub         rsp,28h  
 lea         rcx,[string "%i" (013FB8ADA0h)]  
 mov         edx,7  
 call        printf (013FB81068h)  
 xor         eax,eax  
 add         rsp,28h  
 ret
```

But if I define my own blank destructor, as in the code above:

```
Foo::bar:
 mov         dword ptr [rdx],7  
 mov         rax,rdx  
 ret  

main:
 sub         rsp,28h  
 lea         rdx,[b]  
 call        Foo::bar (013FA11000h)  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [b]  
 lea         rcx,[string "%i" (013FA1ADA0h)]  
 call        printf (013FA11088h)  
 xor         eax,eax  
 add         rsp,28h  
 ret
```

Compiled as a release build using Visual Studio 2012 (v110), though also tried Visual Studio 2010 (v100).  I tried setting /Ob2 to help persuade it to inline the method with no luck.

I'm not familiar enough with assembly to know exactly what it's trying to do, maybe tomorrow I'll try to figure that out to see it if gives any hints.  Can anyone shed any light on why defining an empty destructor would prevent the method being inlined?

EDIT [17/11/2012]

I updated the code above to be much simpler (originally I was working on my Vector class).

Returning a primitive type from a member method seems to get inlined correctly, it's only an issue when I return an instance of my class.

Comment: was my solution helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio treats classes with destructors (empty or not) as "complex" and they will be more likely to abandon certain optimizations. If your class is simple and speed sensitive, use the default destructor.

Comment: To expand on your answer, the following MSDN article [inline, __inline, __forceinline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88(v=vs.71).aspx) explains that the compiler cannot inline a function if *the function returns an unwindable object by value, when compiled with /GX, /EHs, or /EHa.*  
  
It seems that my object is defined as being unwindable as it has a user defined destructor (even though it's empty). Disabling the "Enable C++ Exceptions" flags allows inlining of the object again.

Comment: NB. Returning a reference (to the object) allows it to be inlined also.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2010 it seems like the compiler calculates the final value in compile time and just loads it up into the stack for value of `a`.
Modifying the code as below did enable this optimization with destructor defined:

```
inline void operator = (const __m128 v)
{
    data = v;
}

inline __m128 operator* (const Vector4& a) const
{ 
    return _mm_mul_ps(data, a.data); 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't completely answer why the compiler isn't inlining the method, though I'll definitely use this when working on my Vector class as I do like this approach.